# ROS2 Security Dynamically Changing Keys

Tags: ros2, ardrone-autonomy

I've been doing research into ROS2/DDS security with autonomous vehicles and have a questions on ROS2 security as a whole. We have a LAN set up with multiple drones in a scenario, assuming that one becomes a Bad Agent and has access to current keys, is there anyway to change the key store dynamically without having to shutdown the robot or can they be changed on the flight whenever you want?